# Generating log-distributed random variates

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm looking for a numerically stable way to generate random variates that are distributed like $\log(U)$ with $U \in (0,1)$, to be stored in IEEE 754 floating-point variables. My idea is:

1. Generate mantissa $m$ from $M \sim \log \left(U_{(e,e^2)}\right) \sim 1 + \log (1 + U \cdot (e-1))$.
2. Generate exponent $x$ from $X \sim \lfloor U_{(1,k+1)}\rfloor \sim 1+\lfloor kU\rfloor$ with $k = \text{maximum size of exponent}$.
3. Result: $-m \cdot 2^x$.

Is this a valid way to generate log-distributed random variates up to machine precision? (I'm sure this has been described before, but where?)

If yes, we need to prove that $Y =M \cdot 2^X \sim \log\left(U_{(\exp (2^{-k}), 1)}\right) = L$. Is it safe to claim that $Y \sim \sum_{i=1}^k 2^{-i}M$ from the definition of the product of random variables?

Answer (score 1):

I was totally wrong. $\log(U) \sim -\text{Exp}(1)$, where Exp is the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Simple as that.

In fact, taking the log of the Uniform is one method for [generating random variates from the Exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates). Others include [Ziggurat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) which is based on rejection sampling.